# Disable/Remove Signature from draft created with Apps Script / Google Card Service

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Card Service to create a button, that when clicked should create a new Gmail draft; the draft should open for editing with a pre-populated body, and without a signature.

This is my code:

```
function onHomepage(e) {
    var builder = CardService.newCardBuilder();
    var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Button')
        .setComposeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('doStuff'),
        CardService.ComposedEmailType.STANDALONE_DRAFT));
    builder.addSection(section);

    return builder.build();
}

function doStuff(e){
    var body = 'This is a <b>test</b>'
    var draft = GmailApp.createDraft('','Subject','',{htmlBody: body});

    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
    .setGmailDraft(draft)
    .build();
}
```

The draft is created and opened for editing, the only issue is that the signature of the user is appended after the html body. I've seen other questions about adding a signature to the draft; I however need to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't currently possible.

I would suggest filing a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker detailing the behaviour you would like to see, I would file it either under the [Apps Script component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) or the [Workspace Add-ons component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206).

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate. I've filed a feature request under the Add-ons component as suggested. Thank you for the answer!